# model_main.py does not work with own dataset, created by using old guide

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

#### System information

- **What is the top-level directory of the model you are using?**: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28
- **OS Platform and Distribution**: Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from**: source
- **TensorFlow version**: 1.9
- **Bazel version**: 0.15.0
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 9.2 / 7.1.4
- **GPU model and memory**: GTX 1080

I made my own dataset using that and similar examples:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

My directory for using the TF Object Detection API looks like this:

```
+ ~/recognition
    + data
        - label_map.pbtxt
        - train.record
        - eval.record
    + models
        + ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco
```

I have three classes, and I indicated this in `data/label_map.pbtxt` and `models/models/pipeline.config`.

I used these commands, and it works with my dataset:

```
python object_detection/legacy/train.py --logtostderr
    --pipeline_config_path=path/to/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/pipeline.config
    --train_dir=path/to/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/train

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python object_detection/legacy/eval.py
    --checkpoint_dir=path/to/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/train --logtostderr
    --pipeline_config_path=path/to/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/pipeline.config
    --eval_dir=path/to/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco/eval
```

But when I try to use:

```
python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --num_eval_steps=${NUM_EVAL_STEPS} \
    --alsologtostderr
```

I get errors that will be listed below.

I use Python 3 (tried 3.5 and 3.6) with virtualenv.

Do I understand correctly that `using_your_own_dataset`-example is obsolete and now I need to create my own dataset a little differently?

Where can I get a new guide?

My errors log:

https://pastebin.com/4JJ5UQTD

Comment: still an issue? Have you modified your config file? SSD and batching in general only works if your imput images are all the same size. If you're somehow  using the keep_aspect_ratio_resizer the above error could appear.